# Sent mail being received in POP3 client

Tags: gmail, outlook, pop3

I've recently set up my Gmail account in Outlook and am running into an issue where sent email is being duplicated in my Outlook Inbox.  In Gmail, everything looks fine.  The mail is in the Sent label, and my Inbox is empty.  The sent mail shows going to only the recipients I added, not CC or BCC.

However, Outlook receives a copy of each Sent email in the Inbox every time it checks the POP3 server.  While I would prefer to use IMAP, I cannot for this particular application, it must be POP3.

There are no filters set up on my Gmail or Outlook, nor are there any Labs plugins running.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you receive sent mails on your POP3 inbox is because the sent emails are being sent from the web client directly and not through some 3rd party such as Outlook. If your send an email from outlook it will not send you your sent email again. However if someone does email from the web client directly. ie . from the website a copy of the sent email will be sent to the POP3 account.

Comment: Could you link an authorative source that confirms this?